# Верстка макета.Как мне сделать правильно position absolute за межи контейнера?

Tags: html, css

написал, так, но работает плохо адаптивно, когда делаю ширину екрана меньше, тогда картинка перекрывает текст.
планшет выходит за межи контейнера, я так понял что надо позиционировать абсолютно, я пробовал, но ломает адаптив, когда ширина меньше контейнера, то появляется прокрут,только работает все адаптивно если планшет поставить в контейнер, но на макете по другому, какие стили надо написать чтоб планшет вышел за межи контейнера, и адаптивная картинка была

[image: планшет выходит за межи контейнера, я так понял что надо позиционировать абсолютно, я пробовал, но ломает адаптив, когда ширина меньше контейнера, то появляется прокрут,только работает все адаптивно если планшет поставить в контейнер, но на макете по другому, какие стили надо написать чтоб планшет вышел за межи контейнера, и адаптивная картинка была?]

```css
    .container{
       width: 100%;
       max-width: 1230px;
       padding: 0px 15px;
       margin: 0 auto;}

    .your--browser{
    display: flex;
    }
.your--browser__ipad--img{
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
        <html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
           <div class="container">
                    <div class="your--browser">
                   <div class="your--browser__info">
                      <h2 class="your--browser__title">All You need is a browser!</h2>
                      <p class="your--browser__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
                         eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                      </p>
                      <p class="your--browser__description">
                         Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
                         ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                      </p>
                      <div class="your--browser__marked">
                         <img src="img/marked.png" alt="marked" class="your--browser__marked-icon">
                         <div class="your--browser__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="your--browser__marked">
                         <img src="img/marked.png" alt="marked" class="your--browser__marked-icon">
                         <div class="your--browser__text">Ut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud</div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="your--browser__ipad">
                      <img class="your--browser__ipad--img" src="http://placehold.it/350x400" alt="">
                   </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ответов Ноль почему то - https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/bGexZJL - так может быть ?